# How can one select components based on some supposed sizes in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, wolfram-mathematica

do Matlab has alternative for `SelectComponents` function in mathematica?

how could this wolfram mathematica code be converted to its matlab equivalent.

```
(* Connected component selection based on some supposed sizes. *)
ccs = SelectComponents[wsthick, "Count", 1000 < # < 3000 || 6000 < # < 10000 &]
```

Comment: what does `SelectComponents` do exactly? maybe provide an example (input data, output data and an explanation thereof)?

Comment: @ThijsW   http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SelectComponents.html

Comment: @Suvidha yes, I had seen that, but it is not very clear to me what exactly what the line of code in your question should do. If you provide an example, I could give it a shot in matlab, but i'm not going to install mathematica first to try it out..

Comment: @ThijsW please refer to this question and the first answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935377/detecting-object-in-homogeneous-intensity-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab you can use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) for computing different properties of labeled regions in an image.

For your question I would try

```
lb = bwlabel( wsthick, 4 ); % use 4-connect regions in bw image
s = regionprops( lb, 'Area', 'PixelIdxList' );  % extract area of regions - number of pixels they cover
count = [s(:).Area] ; % a vector with count for each region
sel = ( ( count > 1000 & count < 3000 ) | ( count > 6000 & count < 10000 );
ccs = false( size( wsthick ) );
ccs( vertcat( s(sel).PixelIdxList ) ) = true;
```

Might not be as elegant as in Mathematica, but works just the same.

Comment: am getting error in last line of the code. Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not
consistent.