# Detecting shape from the predefined shape and cropping the background

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have several images of the pugmark with lots of irrevelant background region. I cannot do intensity based algorithms to seperate background from the foreground.
I have tried several methods. one of them is [detecting object in Homogeneous Intensity image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935377/detecting-object-in-homogeneous-intensity-image)
but this is not working with rough texture images like

http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/4654/p1030076b.jpg

http://imageshack.us/a/img802/5982/cub1.jpg

http://imageshack.us/a/img42/6530/cub2.jpg

Their could be three possible methods :

1) if i can reduce the roughness factor of the image and obtain the more smoother texture i.e more flat surface.

2) if i could detect the pugmark like shape in these images by defining rough pugmark shape in the database and then removing the background to obtain image like https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyqIU.png

3) if i could detect the regions with depth and separating them from the background based on difference in their depths.

please tell if any of these methods would work and if yes then how to implement them.

Comment: good luck with that...

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that this problem could benefit from using polynomial texture maps.
See here: http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/ptm/

Comment: yeah it seems it would work .. but the database has already been collected. and this method requires same pugmark image in different lightening conditions. Anyway thanks a lot for your help, it helped to learn something new :)

Comment: If it's a one-off thing, there aren't too many images, and you have a few hundred dollars of budget, why not just turn it into a series of Mechanical Turk tasks and let the wisdom of the crowds be you computer vision machine?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider top-down information in the process. See, for example, [this work](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~levina/papers/CRFs-eccv06.pdf).

Comment: thank you for your help .. but honestly i am new at image processing and that was all greek to me. besides what little i interpreted ..it would not work on my images.

Comment: @Suvidha - As a person with slightly more experience in image processing and computer vision, I can tell you that the task you wish to perform is very **nontrivial**. I think you are facing the following choice: If you want to pursue this task yourself, you'll have to dedicate a lot of time to learn computer vision beyond the very basics (for instance, making sense of the paper I sent to you - which is quite common practice). Another option you may consider is  hiring an expert that will perform this task for you.

Comment: @Suvidha - Alternatively, you may decide to abandon the automatic way of segmenting the images and it will take you less time to annotate the photos yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're close enough from the pugmark, so I think that you should be able to detect pugmarks using [Viola Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) algorithm. Maybe a PCA-like algorithm such as [Eigenface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) would work too, even if you're not trying to recognize a particular pugmark it still can be used to tell whether or not there is a pugmark in the image.

Have you tried edge detection on your image ? I guess it should be possible to finetune [Canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) thresholds in order to get rid of the noise (if it's not good enough, low pass filter your image first), then do shape recognition on what remains (you would then be in the field of [geometric feature learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_feature_learning) and structural matching) Viola Jones and possibly PCA-like algorithm would be my first try though.